# Javascript - if else not setting var

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am having a bit of trouble with some javascript, I have searched for a question with an answer to this, but since it is probably one of the easiest things to do, I doubt anyone but myself could get it wrong.

I'm trying to simply make a content switcher, but the if statement that moved onto the next piece of content does not seem to be working:

```
//Work out next box
if (i == 2){var x=1;}else{var x=i+1;}
```

I've created a quick js fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/TuMEa/5/) to try and get this working, I would be glad if someone could help me, thank you :)

(I have very little JS knowledge, but some programming knowledge (so I understand what things do))

Comment: You forgot to post a link to JSFiddle.

Comment: are u aware that `x` is only useful inside brackets `{}`?

Comment: Why not `var x = i == 2 ? 1 : i + 1;`? Also *variable scope*... Please see [SO: JavaScript Variable Scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

Comment: Probs just an example, methodology is the question not optimisation

Comment: JavaScript uses function scoped variables, so the `x` should be accessible from outside the brackets.

Comment: You shouldn't really be declaring vars within conditional statements.

Comment: Whoops... posted jsfiddle link, I am now aware, but wasn't aware before about the scope in {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a variable there are 2 parts to it:

- declaration
- definition

Also, `{}` creates a `scope`.

A variable lives (can be used) in the scope where it was declared.

#### Declaration

```
 var x;
```

A declaration means telling the program that inside this scope there is a variable called `x`.

#### Definition

```
 x = 3;
```

A definition means telling the program what value that variable holds ( points to ) and it can only be done if the variable was defined first.

As you can see here, you have to declare your variable outside of the accolades, in a common `scope` for both the `if` and the `else`.

http://jsfiddle.net/2hwG7/

```
var x, i = 1;
if (i == 2)
    x=1;
else
    x=i+1;

console.log(x);
```

#### The ?: operator

Also, as other users mentioned, in javascript there is a `ternary operator`([conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)).

Usage:

`condition ? action1 : action2;`

The above translates to:

`if(condition)
      action1;
 else
      action2;`

It is called `ternary operator` because it is using 3 `operands`.

Comment: Why not simple `var x = i == 2 ? 1 : i + 1;`?

Comment: Because the user must learn. And it is easier for him to learn this way.

Comment: It would be nice if you add about [condition operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) also.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, helped me, and thanks for making it really descriptive, marked as answer

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 0;
x = 0;


if (i == 2){x=1;}else{x=i+1;}

console.log(x);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9TXJ9/

You are using `var` which creats the variable in the block scope only.